# Where to start building a blockchain on EOSIO

Tags: development, blockchains

Where can I find a step by step or at least the docs on how to create a blockchain on EOSIO? Their website has a bunch of resources but mostly for apps and smart contracts, but not clear info on actual blockchain development

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/getting-started/index has a pretty good guide about how to use the eosio software to create a new blockchain.